# dataframe - timespan between timestamps based on value of other column

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the index containing years and a column containing dividend payouts. I now want to determine how many years the company has continuously paid out dividends (column dividend > 0).

As an example, for the following table I want the result to be 2 (2019+2018)

```
year dividend
2019 1.89
2018 1.70
2017 0
2016 1.5
```

And for this one 4

```
year dividend
2019 1.89
2018 1.70
2017 1.6
2016 1.58
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhough the below answer is a round about, yet it can solve your problem.

Convert it to `pd.df` and use [idxmin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) with [ne()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) wrapper to find the continuous divident pay.

```
year dividend
2019 1.89
2018 1.70
2017 0
2016 1.5

df = pd.DataFrame({'dividend' : [1.89,1.70,0,1.5]}, index=[2019,2018,2017,2016])
print('Continuous Divident value :', df.loc[ : df.dividend.idxmin()].ne(0).sum()[0])

Continuous Divident value : 2

year dividend
2019 1.89
2018 1.70
2017 1.6
2016 1.58

df = pd.DataFrame({'dividend' : [1.89,1.70,1.6,1.58]}, index=[2019,2018,2017,2016])
print('Continuous Divident value :', df.loc[ : df.dividend.idxmin()].ne(0).sum()[0])

Continuous Divident value : 4
```

Edit

Based on your comment, I just played with loops, I hope this satisfy your requiremnts. If not let me know..

```
value = 0 if df['bool'].iloc[0] == 0 else (len(df) if len(df) == df.iloc[-1::]['bool'].values[0] else len(df.loc[: df[df['bool'].duplicated(keep = 'last')].index[0]]))
print('Continous divident value : ', value)
```

Comment: I just noticed that it doesn't work properly in case the column "dividend" has multiple times the same minimum value. E.g. say in my second example above dividend is 1.58 in 2019, then the result of your code is 1 whilst it should be 4. Any idea?

Comment: Whether this case also to be included -  if 2019 = 0,remaining years are > 0, then continuos divi = 3 ??

Comment: See the edited version, does it satisfy your requirement ?